# How can I get words from brackets in String?

Tags: java, string

I have various sql requests.For example

```
SELECT COUNT(project_id) AS 'count', project.name AS 'projects' FROM test
JOIN project ON project_id = project.id
```

or

```
SELECT count(*) AS 'browsers' FROM `test`
```

I want to receive words that are in ''. For example 'count', 'projects', 'browsers'.
Thus, I want to get the names of the columns from the table.But how can I do this, something I don't understand.So far I just wrote

```
  String[] str = sqlRequest.split("FROM");
```

but what can I write next, I don’t guess. Tell me how you can get words from these brackets?

Comment: Do you want only columns names, so words which are between 'SELECT' and 'FROM'?

Comment: yes,you are right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it as follow:

```
String query = "SELECT COUNT(project_id) AS 'count', project.name AS 'projects' FROM test JOIN project ON project_id = project.id";
LinkedList<String> queryColumns = new LinkedList<>();
String[] test = query.replace("SELECT", "").split("FROM")[0].split(","); //You have a string from which you need to extract single names, taking care of aliases.
for(String s : test) {
    int aliasIndex = s.indexOf("AS");
    String column;
    if(aliasIndex != -1) {
        //if there is an alias
        column = s.substring(aliasIndex + 2).replace("'","").strip();
    } else {
        //if there isn't an alias
        column = s.replace("'","").strip();
    }
    queryColumns.add(column);
}
```

I assume that the alias is indicated as 'AS' in uppercase, if it can be lowercase too, it's easy to change and adapt the code.

Comment: Thank you.Its work

Answer (score 2):

Don't do this with String split, replace etc. At some point, it will fail.

You should parse the sql statement. Example with [JsqlParser](https://github.com/JSQLParser/JSqlParser) like

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JSQLParserException {

        Select stmt = (Select) CCJSqlParserUtil.parse(
                "SELECT COUNT(project_id) AS 'count', project.name AS 'projects' FROM test\n"
                + "JOIN project ON project_id = project.id ");

        for (SelectItem selectItem : ((PlainSelect) stmt.getSelectBody()).getSelectItems()) {
            selectItem.accept(new SelectItemVisitorAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void visit(SelectExpressionItem item) {
                    System.err.println(item.getAlias().getName());
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
'count'
'projects'
```